# Different y-scales for different rows of facet_wrap

Tags: r, ggplot2, facet-wrap

How can I have individual y-scales for every row of my `facet_wrap` plot?
I tried `scales="free_x"` but that's not working. All y scales have the same max (see image). Any help is much appreciated!

```
ggplot() + 
    geom_bar(data=uws, aes(y = as.numeric(Costs), x = Scenario, 
         fill = Component), stat="identity",position='stack') + 
    ggtitle("Title") +
    xlab ("Xlab") +    
    ylab ("Ylab") +
    theme_bw() +  
    facet_wrap( ~ PE,scales="free_x",)
```

[image]

This is the data set:

```
Scenario;Component;PE;Costs;;;
Conv;Wastewater Conveyance;PE 5,000;1356360;;;
ConvR;Wastewater Conveyance;PE 5,000;1356360;;;
OS_6;Wastewater Conveyance;PE 5,000;0;;;
OS_200;Wastewater Conveyance;PE 5,000;0;;;
Conv;Wastewater Treatment;PE 5,000;17549257;;;
ConvR;Wastewater Treatment;PE 5,000;18587385;;;
OS_6;Wastewater Treatment;PE 5,000;7773436;;;
OS_200;Wastewater Treatment;PE 5,000;2121721;;;
Conv;Wastewater Conveyance;PE 10,000;2712720;;;
ConvR;Wastewater Conveyance;PE 10,000;2712720;;;
OS_6;Wastewater Conveyance;PE 10,000;0;;; 
OS_200;Wastewater Conveyance;PE 10,000;0;;;
Conv;Wastewater Treatment;PE 10,000;28022421;;;
ConvR;Wastewater Treatment;PE 10,000;28835132;;;
OS_6;Wastewater Treatment;PE 10,000;15542442;;;
OS_200;Wastewater Treatment;PE 10,000;4243441;;;
Conv;Wastewater Conveyance;PE 50,000;13563602;;;
ConvR;Wastewater Conveyance;PE 50,000;13563602;;;
OS_6;Wastewater Conveyance;PE 50,000;0;;;
OS_200;Wastewater Conveyance;PE 50,000;0;;;
Conv;Wastewater Treatment;PE 50,000;83067897;;;
ConvR;Wastewater Treatment;PE 50,000;76961846;;;
OS_6;Wastewater Treatment;PE 50,000;77707777;;;
OS_200;Wastewater Treatment;PE 50,000;21217207;;;
Conv;Wastewater Conveyance;PE 100,000;27127203;;;
ConvR;Wastewater Conveyance;PE 100,000;27127203;;;
OS_6;Wastewater Conveyance;PE 100,000;0;;;
OS_200;Wastewater Conveyance;PE 100,000;0;;;
Conv;Wastewater Treatment;PE 100,000;132642459;;;
ConvR;Wastewater Treatment;PE 100,000;114470019;;;
OS_6;Wastewater Treatment;PE 100,000;155411123;;;
OS_200;Wastewater Treatment;PE 100,000;42434414;;;
Conv;Wastewater Conveyance;PE 500,000;135636017;;;
ConvR;Wastewater Conveyance;PE 500,000;135636017;;;
OS_6;Wastewater Conveyance;PE 500,000;0;;;
OS_200;Wastewater Conveyance;PE 500,000;0;;;
Conv;Wastewater Treatment;PE 500,000;393202029;;;
ConvR;Wastewater Treatment;PE 500,000;254368246;;;
OS_6;Wastewater Treatment;PE 500,000;777051183;;;
OS_200;Wastewater Treatment;PE 500,000;212172070;;;
Conv;Wastewater Conveyance;PE 1,000,000;271272033;;;
ConvR;Wastewater Conveyance;PE 1,000,000;271272033;;;
OS_6;Wastewater Conveyance;PE 1,000,000;0;;;
OS_200;Wastewater Conveyance;PE 1,000,000;0;;;
Conv;Wastewater Treatment;PE 1,000,000;627866807;;;
ConvR;Wastewater Treatment;PE 1,000,000;322083412;;;
OS_6;Wastewater Treatment;PE 1,000,000;1554097935;;;
OS_200;Wastewater Treatment;PE 1,000,000;424344140;;;
Conv;Wastewater Conveyance;PE 1,500,000;406908050;;;
ConvR;Wastewater Conveyance;PE 1,500,000;406908050;;;
OS_6;Wastewater Conveyance;PE 1,500,000;0;;;
OS_200;Wastewater Conveyance;PE 1,500,000;0;;;
Conv;Wastewater Treatment;PE 1,500,000;825586397;;;
ConvR;Wastewater Treatment;PE 1,500,000;346318552;;;
OS_6;Wastewater Treatment;PE 1,500,000;2331144688;;;
OS_200;Wastewater Treatment;PE 1,500,000;636516210;;;
Conv;Wastewater Conveyance;PE 2,000,000;542544067;;;
ConvR;Wastewater Conveyance;PE 2,000,000;542544067;;;
OS_6;Wastewater Conveyance;PE 2,000,000;0;;;
OS_200;Wastewater Conveyance;PE 2,000,000;0;;;
Conv;Wastewater Treatment;PE 2,000,000;1002582289;;;
ConvR;Wastewater Treatment;PE 2,000,000;346166913;;;
OS_6;Wastewater Treatment;PE 2,000,000;3108195871;;;
OS_200;Wastewater Treatment;PE 2,000,000;848688280;;;
Conv;Wastewater Conveyance;PE 2,500,000;678180083;;;
ConvR;Wastewater Conveyance;PE 2,500,000;678180083;;;
OS_6;Wastewater Conveyance;PE 2,500,000;0;;;
OS_200;Wastewater Conveyance;PE 2,500,000;0;;;
Conv;Wastewater Treatment;PE 2,500,000;1165608955;;;
ConvR;Wastewater Treatment;PE 2,500,000;329578002;;;
OS_6;Wastewater Treatment;PE 2,500,000;3885242623;;;
OS_200;Wastewater Treatment;PE 2,500,000;1060860350;;;
```

Comment: I think you just need ```scales = "free_y"```. Were you looking for something more nuanced?

Comment: Also it would be helpful if you could provide a sample of your data so that your question is reproducible and answerers can help you with your exact problem.

Comment: Thank you for your response! 
@Nancy scale_y does not do the job. I've tried it before but it generates individual scales for all plots. I want a constant scale for the first, second and third row of the facet plot.

I added the data set to the question.

Comment: I don't think that's possible with facets. Grid.arrange might be a possibility

Comment: Hmm, too bad! Thanks anyway!